# Rails4: ForbiddenAttributesError on Model Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I get a ForbiddenAttributesError when I send an update to my Rails 4 controller.

The model is 'Company' and it has a private method in it's controller:

```
 def company_params
  params.require(:company).permit( :adress_id,
                                  :name,
                                  :zusatz,
                                  :kontakt,
                                  :strasse,
                                  :adresszusatz,
                                  :plz,
                                  :ort,
                                  :telefon,
                                  :fax,
                                  :natel,
                                  :email,
                                  :alternative_email,
                                  :url,
                                  :anbieter_id,
                                  :eintrittsdatum,
                                  :betrag,
                                  :bemerkungen,
                                  :betrag_gwrj,
                                  :betrag_sgkv,
                                  :rechnungszusatz,
                                  :zusatzfeld_7,
                                  :zusatzfeld_8,
                                  :zusatzfeld_9,
                                  :zusatzfeld_10,
                                  :datum_mutation,
                                  :verzeichnis_id,
                                  :industry_ids => []#,
                                  #:latitude,
                                  #:longitude 
                                  )
end
```

BetterErrors shows me these Request parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"0rDHB7BNuHikL3/Fktdaj6BFFDinpUwPdpy+12HdMw4=", "company"=>{"adress_id"=>"", "name"=>"AGIP Tankstelle Rapperswil", "zusatz"=>"", "kontakt"=>"Eni Suisse S.A.", "strasse"=>"Zürcherstrasse 92", "adresszusatz"=>"", "plz"=>"8640", "ort"=>"Rapperswil", "telefon"=>"", "fax"=>"", "natel"=>"", "email"=>"", "url"=>"", "anbieter_id"=>"", "eintrittsdatum"=>"", "betrag"=>"", "bemerkungen"=>"", "betrag_gwrj"=>"", "betrag_sgkv"=>"", "rechnungszusatz"=>"", "zusatzfeld_7"=>"test", "zusatzfeld_8"=>"", "zusatzfeld_9"=>"", "zusatzfeld_10"=>"", "datum_mutation"=>"", "verzeichnis_id"=>"HR & Stadt", "alternative_email"=>""}, "commit"=>"Speichern", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"companies", "id"=>"375"}
```

The form looks like this:

```
...
<%= form_for @company, url: {action: "update"}, html: {class: "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :adress_id %>
        <%= f.text_field :adress_id %>
      </div>
...
      <%= f.submit "Speichern" %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
```

And this is the Update Method in the controller:

```
def update 
@company = Company.find(params[:id])
if @company.update_attributes(params[:company])
  redirect_to(@company)
else
  render :edit
end
end
```

If I use the "company" hash in the rails console and create a company via Company.create [hash], it works fine. Any idea why Rails is throwing this error at me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure than in your controller you're using company_params in `update_attributes`:

```
  def update
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|

      # Here use company_params and not params[:company]
      if @company.update_attributes(company_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'company updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, I just added my update method. Only difference I can see is that you use company_params and I use params[:company].